# Contradiction Involving Division Algorithm.

Tags: algorithms

Given the smallest positive integer $d$ such that $d = ax + by$, prove that $d\mid a$. To do this, you must use a proof of contradiction. Assume $d$ doesn't divide $a$, and apply the division algorithm. Explain why $r$ can't be zero, then use $r = a-qd$ to derive a contradiction.

I've started by writing out that $a ≠ qd + r$, which means $r ≠ a - qd$. From there, I can't really find a contradiction.

Comment: First,   I'm assuming that problem means smallest positive integer d?  Since A:  That's the actual gcd that this problem is talking about, and B:  otherwise no such animal exists

Comment: Yes, the problem states that d is the smallest positive integer.

Comment: Hint: Integers of that form are closed under subtraction, and under scaling by any integer, so they are closed under the remainder operation. Thus $\,a\ {\rm mod}\ d\,$ has that form so it must $= 0\,$ (else it would be positive and smaller than $\,d,\,$ contra hypothesis).$\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is the remainder of the division of $a$ by $d$, then $r>0$ precisely when $d\nmid a$. Also, $0\le r<d$ by definition.

So, if $a$ is not divisible by $d$, you can find $r$, with $0<r<d$ such that $a=dq+r$, for some $q$. Then
$$
a=(ax+by)q+r
$$
or
$$
r=a(1-xq)+b(-yq)
$$
so…

Comment: Hi, After that, am I supposed to show that r = 0, thus a contradiction? If I am, how could I show r = 0?

Comment: @IanMurphy You find a contradiction, because $r>0$ has the same form as $d$ (a linear combination of $a$ and $b$), but is less than the minimum. So $r$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at *any* integer in the form $s=ax+by$. Use the division algorithm for $d$ into $s$. Look closely at the remainder. Can it be anything other than zero?

If the remainder must be zero, then $d$ always divides any $s=ax+by$. Then what about $a$ which equals $a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 0$?